# how to get longest sub ascending array, which is not necessarily have to be contiguous

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I want to get the longest subarray from a large list. For simplfy, I just show a slice of the array:

```py
a = [1263, 1270, 1265, 1267, 1266, 1269, 1271, 1272, 1268, 1264, 1288, 1289, 1261, 1262, 1284, 1277, 1278, 1281, 1273, 1279, 1280, 1296]
```

The output should keep as many elements as possible in ascending order. The output does not necessarily have to be contiguous.
I got the output manually, and found that it should have 11 elements:

```py
[1263, 1265, 1266, 1269, 1271, 1272, 1277, 1278, 1279, 1280, 1296]
```

However, I can only get 7 elements array from my code:

```py
def get_ascending_sub_array(arr):
    if not arr:
        return arr
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    else:
        sub_arr = [ arr[0] ]
        for i in range(1,len(arr)):
            if arr[i] > sub_arr[-1]:
                sub_arr.append(arr[i])
        return sub_arr



def get_longest_sub_ascending_array(arr):
    outarr = []
    if not arr:
        return arr
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    max_len = 0
    max_arr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if len(arr[i:]) > max_len:
            arr_start_at_i = get_longest_sub_ascending_array(arr[i:])
            if len(arr_start_at_i) > max_len:
                max_len = max_len
                max_arr = get_ascending_sub_array(arr[i:])
    outarr = max_arr
    return outarr

print get_ascending_sub_array(a)
```

output:

```py
[1263, 1270, 1271, 1272, 1288, 1289, 1296]
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thank you for any suggestions.

---

Finally, I found this answer from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construction-of-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming/):

```py
# Dynamic Programming solution to construct Longest 
# Increasing Subsequence 

# Utility function to print LIS 
def printLIS(arr): 
    arr = list(arr)
    for x in arr: 
        print x,
    print 
    print len(arr)

# Function to construct and print Longest Increasing 
# Subsequence 
def constructPrintLIS(arr, n): 
    arr = list(arr)
    n = int(n)

    # L[i] - The longest increasing sub-sequence 
    # ends with arr[i] 
    l = [[] for i in range(n)] 

    # L[0] is equal to arr[0] 
    l[0].append(arr[0]) 

    # start from index 1 
    for i in range(1, n): 

        # do for every j less than i 
        for j in range(i): 

            # L[i] = {Max(L[j])} + arr[i] 
            # where j < i and arr[j] < arr[i] 
            if arr[i] > arr[j] and (len(l[i]) < len(l[j]) + 1): 
                l[i] = list(l[j]) #.copy() 

        # L[i] ends with arr[i] 
        l[i].append(arr[i]) 

    # L[i] now stores increasing sub-sequence of 
    # arr[0..i] that ends with arr[i] 
    maxx = l[0] 

    # LIS will be max of all increasing sub- 
    # sequences of arr 
    for x in l: 
        if len(x) > len(maxx): 
            maxx = x 

    # max will contain LIS 
    printLIS(maxx) 



# This code is contributed by 
# sanjeev2552 





a = [1263, 1270, 1265, 1267, 1266, 1269, 1271, 
     1272, 1268, 1264, 1288, 1289, 1261, 1262, 1284, 
     1277, 1278, 1281, 1273, 1279, 1280, 1296]

print constructPrintLIS(a, len(a))
```

Comment: can you explain, what exactly output you want? how can you get 9 element as output ?

Comment: But 1265, 1267 are contiguous, why are they in the list?

Comment: @Sandy `Subarray != subsequence`

Comment: @MrNobody33 Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question. The output does not necessarily have to be contiguous. I just want as many elements as possible in ascending order.

Comment: @vivek_23 I mean sub-array. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Sandy You said _The output does not necessarily have to be contiguous_ this is a subsequence my friend and not a subarray.

Comment: @vivek_23 I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem.

The algorithm is described in the Wikipedia link above. I suggest you use the algorithm they describe, which runs rather quickly (`O(n log n)`).

If you do not understand it well, you also can compute the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) between `arr` and `sorted(arr)` using a dynamic programming algorithm. It will run in `O(n²)`, which is suboptimal but still adapted to relatively small inputs.